# How can I check if two models equal each other in Django?

Tags: python, django, models

models.py:

```
class office_list(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    num_of_pax = models.IntegerField()

class tg_list(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    num_of_pax = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I check that the office_list name equals to the tg_list name? 
I want to check if any of the office_list.name == any of the tg_list.name

Comment: you mean data or the declare of the model class?

Comment: `your_office_list.name == your_tg_list.name`. Typically however if you have to do such checks through an entire database, it is better to use foreignkeys.

Comment: well I want to check if any of the office_list.name == any of the tg_list.name? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want

> any of the office_list.name == any of the tg_list.name

you can do simple query with [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

```
names = tg_list.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
office_list.objects.filter(name__in=names).exists()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#comparing-objects) :

To **compare two model** instances, just **use the standard Python comparison** operator, the double equals sign: `==`. Behind the scenes, that compares the primary key values of two models.

**or** :

Youu can do with `__eq__` in python too:

See [python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer requires an DB call, and specifically checks 1 field. In a more realistic scenario, you would be checking some subset of fields to be equal - likely ignoring PK's, creation timestamps, amongst other things.

A more robust solution would be something like:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    some_field_that_is_irrelevant_to_equivalence = models.CharField()
    some_char_field = models.CharField()
    some_integer_field = models.IntegerField()

    _equivalent_if_fields_equal = (
        'some_char_field',
        'some_integer_field',
    )

    def is_equivalent(self, other: 'MyModel') -> bool:
        """Returns True if the provided `other` instance of MyModel
        is effectively equivalent to self.

        Keyword Arguments:
        -- other: The other MyModel to compare this self to
        """
        for field in self._equivalent_if_fields_equal:
            try:
                if getattr(self, field) != getattr(other, field):
                    return False
            except AttributeError:
                raise AttributeError(f"All fields should be present on both instances. `{field}` is missing.")
        return True
```